# sql statement question. Need to query 3 tables in one go!

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have an sql database. In this database is 3 tables I need to query. The first table has all the item info called `item` and the other two tables has data for votes and comments called `userComment` and the third for votes called `userItem`

I currently have a function which uses this sql query to get the latest more popular (in terms of both votes and comments):

```
$sql = "SELECT  itemID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  `itemID`
        FROM   `userItem`
        WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  `itemID`
        FROM    `userComment`
        WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `itemID` > 0
        ) q
GROUP BY
        `itemID`
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC";
```

I know how to change this for either by votes alone or comments....

HOWEVER - I need to query the database to only return the itemID's of the ones which have specific conditions in only the `item` table these are `WHERE categoryID = 'xx' AND typeID = 'xx'`

If the sql ninja could please help me on this one? Do I have to first return the results from the above query and the for each in the array fetched then check each against the `item` table and see if it fits the conditions to build a new array - or is that overkill?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly how your DB is setup or where some of these attributes are but it might be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT  q.itemID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  `itemID`
        FROM   `userItem`
        WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  `itemID`
        FROM    `userComment`
        WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `itemID` > 0
        ) q inner join item i on q.itemID = i.itemID
WHERE i.categoryID = 'xx' AND i.typeID = 'xx'
GROUP BY
        q.`itemID`
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC";
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working? What extra info do you need which you were unsure about? the attributes such as categoryID and itemID are in the table called `item` where all the items are actually stored

Comment: The inner join is acting as a filter for only those items with either votes or comments. Change it to a left join - does that help?

Comment: Returns: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'q.itemID = i.itemID WHERE i.categoryID = '1' AND i.typeID = '1' GROUP BY ' at line 10 - SELECT q.itemID, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ( SELECT `itemID` FROM `userItem` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY UNION ALL SELECT `itemID` FROM `userComment` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( `time` ) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `itemID` > 0 ) q left join item i q.itemID = i.itemID WHERE i.categoryID = '1' AND i.typeID = '1' GROUP BY q.`itemID` ORDER BY cnt DESC

Comment: @Stefan, looks like I left off the "on" keyword.

Comment: This works HOWEVER for example: If i have something with 1 vote and a comment it comes under one with 1 vote and no comment? Why is this?

Comment: It seemed when I swapped the comment statement before UNION ALL to above the vote statement to display the results better! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to include the filter on each of the queries. I would need to verify but I would think that it would perform better as fewer rows are analyzed in the Group By. Thus, I would do something like (this is a guess since we are not told how the `item` table relates to the others):

```
$sql = "Select  itemID, Count(*) AS cnt
From    (
        Select ui.`itemID`
        From `userItem` ui
            Join `item` i
                On i.itemid = ui.itemid
        Where From_UnixTime( `time` ) >= Now() - Interval 1 Day
            And i.categoryID = 'xx'
            And i.typeid = 'xx'
        Union All
        Select uc.`itemID`
        From `userComment` uc
            Join `item` i
                On i.itemid= uc.itemid
        Where From_UnixTime( `time` ) >= Now() - Interval 1 Day
            And uc.itemID > 0
            And i.categoryID = 'xx'
            And i.typeid = 'xx'
        )  q
Group By `itemID`
Order By cnt Desc";
```

Comment: Getting this response, any ideas? Column 'itemID' in field list is ambiguous - SELECT itemID, Count(*) AS cnt FROM ( SELECT `itemID` FROM `userItem` ui JOIN `item` i ON i.itemid = ui.itemid WHERE From_UnixTime( `time` ) >= Now() - Interval 7 Day AND i.categoryID = 'popular' UNION ALL SELECT `itemID` FROM `userComment` uc Join `item` i On i.itemid= uc.itemid Where From_UnixTime( `time` ) >= Now() - Interval 7 Day And uc.itemID > 0 And i.categoryID = 'popular' ) q Group By `itemID` Order By cnt Desc

Comment: @Stefan - You simply need to alias `itemid` that is in each of the inner select clauses. I've updated my post to illustrate.